# HTML5/CSS Sticky Header under image issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, sticky

I want to create a homepage where you see an image at first with the actual navigation bar on the bottom of the browser. When you scroll down the navigation should stick to the top when it reaches the top of the browser.

All the examples I've found work with `<h>` and `<p>` tags but as soon as I insert an `<img>` the header will jump to the top before reaching the top of the browser.

Example code with my `<img>` tag inserted from w3c:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" 
        width="100%" />
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes the code works just fine inside of the browser like here on stackoverflow but as soon as you change the width of the browser it bugs again.

I hope all the given information is enough for someone to help me.
I'm already thankful for any help.

///////////////
EDIT:
///////////////

Since Ballsigno solved my problem another problem occured:
I got 1 Logo on the left of the screen and the navigation on the right. The navigation should have a background as a bar across the screen and the logo should overlap this. When I scroll down i first want the logo (which is for example 250px high) to stick to the top and then when i further scroll down i want the navigation + background (about 100px) also to stick to the top.
I don't know why the white space is generated either. Between the first and the second picture the should only be about 100px (the height of the grey bar(navigation bar).
With this code everything except the background bar works..

Example HTML:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

*{
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-container{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}


.stopleft{
 padding-top: 34%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: solid 0px #000;
 float: left;
}

.stopright{
 padding-top: 44.2%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: solid 0px #000;
 float: right;
}


.whiteBarSmall{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
}

.logo{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  }

.navigation{
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: solid 0px #000;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}

 .navigation ul{
  height: 100px;
 }
  .button{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 25px 20px 25px 20px;
  float: right;
  }

.navBackground{
 border: solid 0px #000;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 background-color: #a7a7a7;
 float: right;
 z-index: -1;
}


.whiteBarLarge{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 10%;
 background-color: #fff;
}


.indexImage{
 width: 100%;
}



.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}



footer{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top:  2.5%;
 background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

.navigation a:link {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}


.navigation a:visited {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.navigation a:focus {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation a:hover {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation a:active {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta name="description" content="…." />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <link rel="icon" href="pics/favicon.ico" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/basics.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/links.css" type="text/css" />
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-container">
        <img src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/e893/th/pre/i/2006/132/b/4/widescreen_dreamy_world_6th_by_grafixeye.jpg" alt="Test header" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="stopleft"></div>
    <div class="stopright"></div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/1600/external-link-squared-filled.png" alt="Logo" width="50%" /></div>
        <div class="navigation">
             <ul>
                <li class="button"><a href="pages/uber_uns.html">Über uns</a></li>
                <li class="button"><a href="pages/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="button"><a href="pages/preise.html">Preise</a></li>
                <li class="button"><a href="pages/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="button"><a href="pages/galerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navBackground"></div>
    <div class="indexImage">
        <img src="http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/dual-monitor-wallpapers-hd_dJyDicr.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="whiteBarLarge">
    </div>
    <div class="indexImage">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUPqqyzvnT6JVdDUeUgzDvX9tUpwjKv59spOBgVdYtf-2EaLhD" alt="" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="whiteBarLarge"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope everything is understandable and someone can help me.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem as your current code seems to work fine.

Comment: @sdlfyeiwyrw If you expand the snippet output to full screen, then the header does indeed jump to the top of the page before it should. This only happens on an enlarged browser window, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, you don't need to implement using JavaScript.
How about just setting position: sticky to your header class?
(In that way, you don't have to worry about the position issues.)

```
.header {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background: #555;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
}
```